# Can I use jQuery library with Ionic 3?

Tags: jquery, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, mobile-development

I have a project using [chessboard.js](http://chessboardjs.com/) as well as some other libraries and all of them are using jQuery intensively. Now I am trying to reuse this code in mobile version using [Ionic Framework](https://ionicframework.com/). I understand that it is possible to use jQuery with Angular and Typescript, but many people argue that it is a bad decision to mix jQuery with Angular due to the slow DOM operations of jQuery. But to rewrite huge libraries from Jquery to Typescript on my own also seem to be a bad decision. So would it worth it to reuse jQuery code in Ionic 3 project or should I consider another options such as [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) which seem to be significantly lesser of suggested options?

Comment: A lot of these kind of libraries are already exported to specific Angular libraries. For chessboard.js for example, you could use https://github.com/theborakompanioni/angular-chessboard/, altough it might be outdated in comparison to chessboard.js itself. Is this an option for you?

Comment: Unfortunately no, because as a matter of fact I made a large number of modifications to the original library to suit the project needs. And there are some other libraries written specifically for the project based on jQuery. So the question is how bad would be to mix jQuery with Angular.